# Kubernetes load balancer distribution mode on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, azure-aks

I'm trying to create a load balancer for azure Kubernetes deployment, I'm using the following yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-api-lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: test-api
```

and run it with

```
kubectl apply -f
```

What I need is to create a balancer with source IP affinity. 
I found the following stuff https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-distribution-mode how to configure it on Azure and modes the LB supports. There is **LoadBalancerDistribution** attribute which specifies the mode type. Unfortunately, I didn't find any documentation how it could be done for Kubernetes deployment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that you want to create a load balance for Kubernets deployment and looking for the configuration file. If it's correct. you can follow this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb . This is a internal load balancer. And it could be external load balancer. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have seen this resource, unfortunately, it has nothing about Load Balancer Distribution mode config stuff

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating session affinity from the Azure LB to a specific node, you should configure it on the Kubernetes service by setting `sessionAffinity` to `ClientIP` as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies).